# Найти число которое состоит из количества цифр в нем

Tags: алгоритм, числа

Здраствуйте, у меня возникла такая проблема, мне нужно в десять клеток вписать такое десятизначное число, что в нулевой клетке будет записано общее количество нулей в этом числе, в клктке "1" будет записано количество одиниц и так далее до "9", где будет записано количество 9-ок в числе. Так вот я никак не могу найти его, уже даже делал перебор всех чисел от 1 миллиарда до 9-ти, не находит, может кто знает есть ли такое число вообще?

Comment: 7210000100 подходит... руками оно ищется. А вообще таких немного

Comment: @pavel Тогда уж 6210001000, нет?

Comment: @Harry а ну да, забыл переместить)

Comment: @Harry Спасибо огромное, мне нужно пересмотреть алгоритм поиска:)

Comment: Ну, вообще-то это *единственное* такое число. Как его искал @pavel, я что-то не очень соображу, но исчерпывающий поиск занимает в общем-то не так уж много времени... Особенно если учесть, что сумма цифр должна быть равна 10 :)

Comment: @Harry начать с 9 и все нули. Добавить единицу. Ну вы поняли)

Comment: @pavel Ну, примерно... :) Олимпиадная математика у меня всегда была куда хуже, чем олимпиадная физика :)

Comment: @pavel Прикинул - у меня на машине в один поток искало примерно 5 минут. Если применить очевидные усовершенствования - что первая цифра не может быть ни 0, ни 9... но так мы дойдем до решения вручную :)

Comment: почему первая цифра не может быть 0? Вполне - типа ноль нолей. А вот следующие цифры, при таком раскладе уже не могут быть нолями. Всмысле, взять, например число 999 999 999 - в нем реально 0 нолей.